# Android-Prev Next button MediaController

Tags: android

I want to show prev next button on my video but I don't know how to
This is my code:

```
 public static void play() {

     mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
     Uri video = Uri.parse(path_uri);
     mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);


     mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
     mVideoView.start();

     mVideoView.requestFocus();
     mDialog.dismiss();
     Sipdroid.setIPTVflag(IPTV_PLAYER_STARTED)
```

Can anyone provide code to enable these buttons?

Comment: why dont you add your own buttons? and handle the events in onClicked?!

Comment: because media controller support these buttons and I just want to enable them. The worst case I can't do that I 'll add my own buttons but I want to use what they already had

Comment: add to ur code: `mediaController.show()`

Comment: Thanks but that did not do the trick. I find these on android develop: The "previous" and "next" buttons are hidden until setPrevNextListeners() has been called-> do you know how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);`

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //next button clicked
  }
}, new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //previous button clicked
  }
});
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

This should do the trick.